# How to access an activity after pressing the button that is connected to a fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

The app does not work when you click the button. It "crashes" straight. Here is the code and the error:

FeedFragment, the code:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView rv;
private PostAdapter postAdapter;
private List<PostBean> postBeans;
private Button button_public_to_feed;`

public FeedFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
    
    button_public_to_feed = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_public_to_feed);
    button_public_to_feed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PublicFeedActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

the err:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
     ComponentInfo{com.example.hits/com.example.hits.Canvas.Activity.PublicFeedActivity}:
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
     android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
     on null object reference
                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
```

Already tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PublicFeedActivity.class);
```

Already tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PublicFeedActivity.class);
```

Already tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), PublicFeedActivity.class);
```

Already tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(new FeedFragment().getActivity, PublicFeedActivity.class);
```

everyone returned the same error to me

A help please !!!!

Comment: Did you check is `button_public_to_feed ` null? You can't operate a null reference.

Comment: I don't think it's a reference, because I did other onClickListener in the same way, the difference was that I call an activity within another activity
This one I call an activity inside a fragment

Comment: are you sure the button with id `button_public_to_feed` is in the fragment? maybe it's outside of the fragment, then you need to get it by `getActivity().findViewById()`

Comment: I'm sure, it's inside the fragment

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me, I found the error. The error caused was in the activity, the problem was that I had put a method that closes the activity in onCreate